# Non-native full screen in Terminal.app

Tags: terminal, iterm, fullscreen

If you press Cmd+Enter on iTerm while having the preference "Use native fullscreen windows" turned off, it goes into fullscreen but not the standard MacOS-way.

Is there a way of doing the same in Terminal.app? I know I can use Ctrl+Cmd+F to enter a *native* full screen. And I know I can maximize the window manually to eventually consume all of the screen, but in this case the title is still visible.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you want to use the native method of going into fullscreen?

Comment: @Kyle The reason was that I _thought_ I couldn't use 2 screens if the one was occupied by a native fullscreen app. But I just learned about the "Displays have separate Spaces" options so. Oh I also dislike the animation effects.

Comment: @Kyle Another reason for this that bugs me a lot: You can't cycle through windows that are natively fullscreen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no support for this in Terminal.app.

Answer (score -1):

### Option 1

There is an incredibly simply answer to your problem:

**Double-click the title bar of the window.**

Double-clicking the window again will return it to the previous size and position.

*Note:* Make sure that "Double-click a window's title bar to zoom" is set under *System Preferences -> Dock*.

[image]

### Option 2

Add a [system-wide keyboard shortcut.](http://simianuprising.com/2010/03/15/mac-osx-setting-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-maximizeresize-window-green-jewel/) for the Zoom action.

Comment: They don't want the title of the window to be visible.

Comment: As @Kyle said, this isn't what I'm searching for since the title bar will still be visible.

Comment: Ahh.  Missed the "title is still visible" bit.  That's a case for native fullscreen then.